Input image size (256*256) doesn't match model (224*224)
i finetuned the vit model from huggingface and wanted to do some prediction
# Get test image from the web
test_image_url = 'something.jpg'

response = requests.get(test_image_url)

test_image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

# Resize and display the image
aspect_ratio = test_image.size[0] / test_image.size[1]
max_height = 250
resized_width = int(max_height * aspect_ratio)
resized_img = test_image.resize((resized_width, max_height))
display(resized_img)

this is the code for the prediction
# Predict the top k classes for the test image
inputs = feature_extractor(images=test_image, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")

outputs = model(**inputs)

logits = outputs.logits

top_classes = torch.topk(outputs.logits, k_for_top_acc).indices.flatten().tolist()

for i, class_idx in enumerate(top_classes):
    print(str(i + 1), "- Predicted class:", model.config.id2label[class_idx])

yet i keep getting this error
ValueError: Input image size (256*256) doesn't match model (224*224).

I bet your problem is that, well, you know, the image size doesn't match the model size.  I'm not being flip - that's what the error message is telling you, and I see no reason to think that it's just saying that in order to annoy you.  The solution is to resize the images before feeding them to the model.  Any image manipulation package will have a function to resample the image.  In PIL the function is named Image.resize.

see, that's the problem, i literally did do that and still got the error so im beyond confused, my only solution now is to redo it and see if it works this time, bc for some reason visual studio doesn't register new code unless i close and reopen it
